# why is onCreate() of the previous activity called when the next activity is finished?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I have an activity, say MainActivity that has just onCreate method (no onResume, onStop, etc)
when a contBut is clicked, another activity, say SecondActivity is started and with pressing exitBut, we navigate back to MainActivity. in this case, onCreate of MainActivity is recalled which I can't figure why. I expect it to resume the activity, or at least not to call onCreate.
here is the code for MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Button contBut;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cont);
    contBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View view) {
             Log.d("d", "in count onclick");
           Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ContActivity.class);
           startActivity(intent);
         }
    });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    } 
}
```

here is the code for SecondActivity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity{

private Button exitBut;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cont);

        exitBut = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        exitBut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               finish();
            }
         });
}

 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
 }

}
```

Comment: onCreate should not get called. is thr any more code involved??

Comment: maybe your MainActivity destroys on some condition! memory Issue or something similar

Comment: Can you post your app manifest as well?

Comment: @vipulmittal, problem solved. I answered my qeustion :)

Answer (score 3):

problem solved.
in the developer options section of my device, "Don't keep activities" was checked.

Comment: It's wise to test your app with and without that setting. It simulates what happens when the system kills your app itself (and what happens when the user resumes the app later on).

Comment: This help me out. i just turn on "Don't keep activities" switch on 2 days ago and i forget to turn off.